# Pass dropdownlist value to textbox using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a button which when clicked should just pass the selected value from dropdownlist to a textbox.Here is the code :

```
    <td>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function calculateCity() {

     var city = document.getElementById('<%= ddlCity.ClientID%>');
     txtCity0.value = city.options[city.selectedIndex].value;
                }
     </script>

     <asp:TextBox ID="txtCity0" runat="server" Width="260px"></asp:TextBox>
     <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCity" runat="server">
     <asp:ListItem Value="1">Mumbai</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Value="2">Pune</asp:ListItem>
     </asp:DropDownList>
     <input id="btnCity" onclick="calculateCity();" type="button" value="Calculate City" /></td>
```

This code just doesnt do anything.Any help will be appreciated.Thank You

Comment: This is totally unrelated to your question, but out of curiosity. Why are you keeping the <script> tag inside <td>? Is there any special requirement? I'd like to know about that.

Comment: No logic as such.I thought the script runs inside the same td where i am using it?

Comment: So, just to let you know, when you call document.AnyXYZfunction(), it works on the whole document. It is better to keep only one script tag for whole page, and keep it in the head. If you are working on a Content page then keep it on top or bottom of the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:-

```
function calculateCity() {
    var city = document.getElementById('<%= ddlCity.ClientID%>');
    document.getElementById('<%= txtCity0.ClientID%>').value = 
                                                city.options[city.selectedIndex].value;
 }
```

Or if you can use `jQuery`, then you can do this:-

```
$("#<%= btnCity.ClientID %>").click(function() {
    $('#<%= txtCity0.ClientID %>').val($('#<%= ddlCity.ClientID %>').val());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are finding the drop down correctly, but then not finding the text box and simply trying to use it.

You need a similar getElementById line for the text box